# Integrate with Office from iOS applications

Tags: ios, excel, ms-office

We want our app to be able to open an Excel document in the Excel app for editing and then be able to come back and see the changes when sent back to our application.

I have not been able to get it to work with OneDrive or SharePoint links although it says that this is possible on this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911482.aspx

Did I misunderstand this somehow?

Comment: I did a bit of digging around, maybe have a look at  Zapier, Microsoft Graph, or Microsoft Excel REST API https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sample-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/11/05/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-rest-api-syntax/

Comment: Thanks for the links! They have been of great help!

Comment: Also this might help too in deciphering the link you posted in question https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: If you are using a UIDocumentPickerViewController to pick files from OneDrive and SharePoint what you will be getting is a url for the cached file (not the original). So in my opinion it doesn't really matter what your source is. However, i.e. only if you are using UIDocumentPickerViewController. I have the same problem, I also can't get it to work. In my case I can't get a valid URL object created using the guidelines given in their documentation. It is always null for me. I'm creating the URL as follows, let ppURL = URL.init(string: "ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|" + url.path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Open the document in the Excel iOS app

Similar to setting mimetypes. You can do this on iOS using the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class.

[Developer.apple.com docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html)

[tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)

### Fetch the contents of the document inside your app

As another commenter suggested, hit the Microsoft Graph API for this one:

```
[[[[[graphClient me] drive] items:<item_id>] request] getWithCompletion:^(MSGraphDriveItem *item, NSError *error){
    //Returns a MSGraphDriveItem object or an error if there was one.
}];
```

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios/blob/master/docs/items.md#get-an-item

Comment: It's not possible to edit documents, when using the UIDocumentInteractionController, is it?
I think the Graph API is the way to go if I don't want to implement my own WOPI host. Thanks!

Comment: But how should I open the items I got from the Graph API for editing in the Excel iOS app?

Comment: Preview means view only. It's not editable, right?